# Friendship model : how to find whether a friendship exists?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, model

I have the following model

```
class User(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(require=True)

class Friendship(db.Model):
    user1 = db.ReferenceProperty(User, collection_name='user1_set')
    user2 = db.ReferenceProperty(User, collection_name='user2_set')
```

I can create friends and friendships.
But how to check whether a friendship exists?
Is there a better way to model the friendship?

Comment: You can never be sure that friendship really exists ;)

Answer (score 1):

This will work fine, but you'll need to be specific about how you define friendships. Consider the following users:

```
a = User(name='a')
a.put()

b = User(name='b')
b.put()
```

You can make two `Friendship` entries for each friendship and query for either one to check the existence of a friendship.

```
f = Friendship(user1=a, user2=b)
f.put()

f = Friendship(user1=b, user2=a)
f.put()

result = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Friendship WHERE user1 = :1 AND user2 = :2", a, b).get()
```

Or, you can make a single `Friendship` and perform two queries each time you want to check the existence of a relationship:

```
f = Friendship(user1=a, user2=b)
f.put()

result = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Friendship WHERE user1 = :1 AND user2 = :2", a, b).get()
if result is None:
  result = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Friendship WHERE user1 = :1 AND user2 = :2", b, a).get()
```

Or, you can make a rule about the ordering in which `Friendship` is defined (such as requiring that the lower alphabetical name go first):

```
f = Friendship(user1=a, user2=b) // 'a' is less than 'b'
f.put()

result = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Friendship WHERE user1 = :1 AND user2 = :2", a, b).get() // 'a' is less than 'b'
```

The last option is most efficient, assuming your ordering isn't complex, but you'll need to worry about edge cases (e.g. two users named John Smith). Hashing the name plus some other property (such as when the user signed up), and then comparing it, will reduce but not prevent the likelihood of this.

Answer (score 1):

Make the friends a ListProperty:

```
class Friendship(db.Model):
    friends = db.ListProperty(db.Key) # db.Key refers to a user
```

Then it's a simple query to find a friendship between two users:

```
def getFriendship(self, userKey1, userKey2):
    query = Friendship.gql("WHERE friends = :1 AND friends = :2", userKey1, userKey2)
    return query.get()
```